# `$RANDOM` is not random within `find`'s `-exec`

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to find and move a whole bunch of folders on a linux box.

All the folders are named the same, so I am using `echo $RANDOM` to provide a random number to use for a folder name.

`echo $RANDOM`
does indeed output a random number every time is is run. However,
   `` find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec mv \'{}\'  \'/raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/`echo $RANDOM` \; ``
uses the same "random" number for every folder, and as a result, only moves one folder.

I think the issue is that the `$RANDOM` is being evaluated immediately when `find` begins to run. How do I escape it so the value of `$RANDOM` is not evaluated until the `-exec` option begins to run (or what is a better way to do this)?

<sup>Note: I'm on busybox, so I can't really install anything.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what the problem actually wound up being.

I eventually gave up, and wrote an external script to pass to `find`'s `-exec`, and that seems to be working.

I'm not sure why I couldn't just put the whole command in one line. It seems there are some odd bugs in the version of busybox and bash I have (this is an **old** version of both. It's busybox 1.1.0, which is from 2006, and bash 3.00.16 which is of a similar age (I cannot find a bash release history)).

Answer (score 7):

You are correct; you didn't quote it, so it's evaluated by the shell while building the `find` command line.  `-exec` doesn't use `bash` normally, though, so if you single-quote it or escape the `$` then it won't be expanded at all.

The solution is to invoke `bash` inside `-exec`:

```
find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec bash -c 'echo $RANDOM' \;
```

Comment: Where is the output going in that case? running it produces a lot of empty lines

Comment: Also, I updated the question a bit. I'm trying to use `\`echo $RANDOM\`` as one of the arguments to another command.

Comment: @FakeName Are you sure you are running that command exactly as given?  It should work.

Comment: You said BusyBox, which makes me wonder if you're getting a usable `bash` under `find`.  (If you're getting empty lines then you're getting the output but `$RANDOM` is unset; this I would expect of non-`bash` shells, in particular from BusyBox's own `ash` clone.)  If you have a separate `bash`, try invoking it by full pathname so BusyBox won't be tempted to substitute its builtin `ash`; at least some versions of BusyBox I've seen on Android will do that substitution (annoying when I found an Android `bash` for my phone!)

Comment: @jw013 - Yes, exactly as it's given. It produces empty lines.

Comment: @geekosaur - `echo $RANDOM` seems to work fine.

Comment: @FakeName replace the `bash` with `ash` and see how that goes.  busybox has `ash` and not `bash` it seems.

Comment: @FakeName, that isn't as useful a test as you think; it will work fine if you're in `bash`, but if your `find` is actually BusyBox then it might well invoke BusyBox's own built-in shell when it sees `-exec bash`.

Comment: @geekosaur - It seems to be a real version of bash: `root@:/bin# ls -la | grep bash
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       666688 Dec 22 23:52 bash
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            4 Dec 22 23:52 sh -> bash`

Comment: and ``find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec /bin/bash -c 'echo $RANDOM' \;`` produces the same result - empty lines.

Comment: @FakeName... that is *not* what I am saying.  Yes, absolutely you have a working `bash`.  BusyBox does *not*, and it is likely to take references to `bash` to mean itself (since that's what BusyBox is for); if `find` is BusyBox, `-exec bash` is likely to mean to it "don't run `bash`, run the BusyBox shell".  Try using a full pathname to `bash` to see if you can get it to run the real `bash` instead of its builtin shell.

Comment: @FakeName, if stdout were going elsewhere you would get *no* output, not blank lines.  I told you that earlier ("If you're getting empty lines...").

Comment: ``find . -type d -exec '/bin/bash -c 'echo test'  ' \;`` also produces empty lines, which is interesting.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in BusyBox then.

Comment: While `find . -type d -exec "/bin/bash -c 'echo test $RANDOM'  " \;` produces hundreds of lines of `test 4621` or similar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3251/discussion-between-fake-name-and-geekosaur)

Comment: @FakeName, that last is expected, the outer double quotes do not prevent interpolation of `$variables` but they *do* prevent interpretation of the single-quotes.

Comment: @geekosaur - but without the outer quotes, I don't get the `test` either.

Comment: Whoa, this `bash` is **ancient**. `root@127.0.0.1:/raid/data/Storage# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the command you're running.

```
mv \'{}\' \'/raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/`echo $RANDOM`
```

`` `echo something` `` is equivalent to `something` (except when `something` contains some special characters, in which case the effect of the additional `echo` and command substitution usually makes things worse). So this is a complicated way of writing

```
mv \'{}\' \'/raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/$RANDOM
```

The shell therefore passes three parameters to the `find` command for the part of the command line represented above: `mv`, `'{}'`, and `'/raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/12345` where `12345` is a random value. Since the value of the `RANDOM` special variable is expanded by the shell before invoking `find`, all the commands executed by `find` will run with the same value. Note also that you have extra single quotes which will be parts of the file names — just drop them.

Since you want to expand `$RANDOM` in each invocation, you need to tell `find` to execute a shell which will execute `mv`, instead of having `find` execute `mv` directly.

```
find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" /raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/$RANDOM' {} \;
```

Note that the [probability of a collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) in the random numbers is pretty high: `$RANDOM` only goes up to 2<sup>15</sup>, so if you're copying more than 213 files, the probability that two files are copied to the same target is more than 50%. It is a very bad idea to use a random name in this context. Instead, use a name that is **guaranteed to be distinct** for every source file. One way to do this is to use a cryptographic hash of the source path:

```
find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" /raid/data/Storage/AppleDouble/$(echo "$0" | md5sum | cut -d " " -f 1)' {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec bash -c ' echo "$0"' {} \;` produces a number of empty lines, and then ``sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file``

Comment: Note that the bash on this device (it's embedded) is pretty old - `root@127.0.0.1:/raid/data/Storage# bash --version GNU bash, version 3.00.16(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Also, `sh` is symlinked to `bash`.

Comment: Or just increment a counter.